# JavaScript create object from another object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object like below:

```
const records = [
  {
    city: "London",
    country: "UK"
  },
  {
    city: "New York",
    country: "USA"
  }
];
```

I need to create another object from the above object like below with additional properties:

```
const metadata = [
  {
    city: {
      value: "London",
      trackChanges: true
    },
    country: {
      value: "UK",
      trackChanges: true
    }
  },
  {
    city: {
      value: "New York",
      trackChanges: false
    },
    country: {
      value: "USA",
      trackChanges: false
    }
  }
];
```

I appreciate your help.

Edit1:

I tried the below approach. But it taking the last object:

```
records.map((record, i) => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(record)) {
    return {
      [key]: {
        value: value,
        trackChanges: false
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Please show us your attempt at creating that object. We can't help you with your non-working code if you don't post it.

Comment: That is an array of objects and you need yourArray.map() to get your output. Have a look at the documentation. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Your return occurs first iteration and never completes the for loop

Comment: It might be an easy solution but here the object keys are dynamic. So not able to create the actual object. I tried for many hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using **Array.map** method and then using Object.keys to loop over the keys.

```js
const records = [
      {
        city: "London",
        country: "UK"
      },
      {
        city: "New York",
        country: "USA"
      }
    ];

var results = records.map(rec => {

    var obj={};
    Object.keys(rec).forEach(key => 
        obj[key] = {value:rec[key],trackChanges:true}
    )
    return obj;
})

console.log(results);
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. But my object keys are dynamic. I can not directly put city and country

Comment: @kukuha , I have updated the answer . Please check